# How to paste and remove current line?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I copy several lines of text and open a brand new file.

If I paste with `p`, I get an empty line above the pasted text.

If I paste with `P`, I get an empty line below the pasted text.

How can I paste and remove/replace/delete the current line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select the current line in visual mode before pasting: `Vp`.

Comment: Makes sense. I was hoping there was something more simple, without visual mode.

Comment: @aharris88 I did a little research on this and I can't find a simpler way to do it. I'd love to be proven wrong, though!

Comment: You can always rebind this key combination to something else (like `noremap p Vp`).

Comment: Yeah, but `p` is too useful to overwrite. `Vp` is fine. I don't need it that often.

Answer (score 3):

As you have mentioned that you want to paste the text in a new file.
This would work once you have the text selected

```
:'<,'>w new_filename
```